# ActiveAdmin sidebar didn't display any records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, sidebar

I am using a ActiveAdmin for building administration interface. So i have **Articles** and **Products** resources, in **Article** show i want to make a sidebar to see what products assigned to this Article. Sidebar is looks okey, but it doesn't display any records.

---

**Rails 4.1.0**

**ActiveAdmin 1.0.0**

**ruby 2.1**

---

**app/admin/article.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article, { :sort_order => :name_asc } do

    # Permitted parameters
    permit_params :title, :description

    # Displayed columns
    index do
        selectable_column
        column :title
        column :description
    default_actions
    end

    # Sidebar for Products by this Article
    sidebar 'Products by this Article', :only => :show do
        table_for Product.joins(:article).where(:article_id => article.id) do |s|
            s.column("Title") { |product| product.title }
        end
    end

    # Filters for title and description
    filter :title,         :as => :select               # :check_boxes (for checkboxes)
    filter :description,   :as => :select
end
```

**app/admin/product.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product, { :sort_order => :name_asc } do

    # Permitted parameters
    permit_params :article_id, :title, :description, :price

    # Displayed columns
    index do
        selectable_column
        column :article, :sortable => :article
        column :title
        column :description
    # Currency helper
        column :price, :sortable => :price do |cur|
            number_to_currency cur.price, locale: :ru
        end
        default_actions
    end

    # Filters for each column within "description"
    filter :article, :as => :select               # :check_boxes (for checkboxes)
    filter :title,   :as => :select
    filter :price
end
```

**app/models/article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationship
    has_many :products

    # Validations
    validates :title, :description, :presence => true
end
```

**app/admin/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationship
    belongs_to :article

    # Validations
    validates :article, :title, :description, :price, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)? It's easier to configure IMO.

Comment: Thank you for advise, but now i am working with this stuff. Ill check rails_admin in future for sure

Comment: Does the same `table_for` setup work elsewhere, like inside the `show` block?

Comment: It's kind of weird because this sidebar construction must working properly. The sidebar displays well, but cannot see any records inside

Comment: its really weird, i've implement same construction in another resources and it works properly well, absolutely same but here doesn't works, please someone can help me solve this.

Comment: Hmm i found one thing in logs WHERE "products"."article_id" IS NULL
article.id is nil!
Anybody can tell me why?